How can i join 3 different alert conditions together with logical operators
I want to join 3 minute macd signal crossover  alert on 3 minute timeframe. The alert should only be activated when 15 seconds macd is under zero line and macd crossover signal. Also same for when 3 minute macd signal crossunder alert on 3 minute timeframe, Alert should only be activated when 15 seconds macd is over zero line and macd crossunder
I already plotted the two macd on same pane which is displayed on the chart. My issue is the alert setting.
I used the code below to set my condition, but no alarm was triggered. Kindly advise. I am not a skilled programmer
macdupcrossAlert = ta.crossover(macd,signal)   ///// 3 minute macd crossover
macddowncrossAlert = ta.crossunder(macd,signal) ////// 3 minute macd crossunder

macdcrossoverAlert_15S = ta.crossover(mtf_15smacd, mtf_15Ssignal) //// 15 seconds macd crossover
macdcrossunderAlert_15S = ta.crossunder(mtf_15smacd, mtf_15Ssignal) //// 15 seconds macd crossunder


condition1 = (macdcrossoverAlert_15S and mtf_15smacd < 0) and macdupcrossAlert  
condition2 = (macdcrossunderAlert_15S and mtf_15smacd > 0) and macddowncrossAlert 

alertcondition(condition1, title="15 seconds up", message="Price is going up!, macd below zero")
alertcondition(condition2, title="15 seconds down", message="Price is going Down! macd above zero")


With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
How do you get the values ​​for 15 seconds (mtf_15smacd and mtf_15Ssignal)?
